# Panasonic lens autofocus does not work with Olympus bodies?

Tags: autofocus, panasonic-lumix

I just got a Panasonic Lumix Nocticron 42.5mm lens and the autofocus does not appear to work with my OM-D E-M1 M2 body.

Is autofocus supposed to work on non-Panasonic bodies for this lens, or no? Is that normal?

**UPDATE**

I tried using the "AF" button on the top of the camera. When I changed the mode using this button, it did autofocus. For example, if I used the button to change it to S-AF, then it would work in that mode. However, the menu setting AF mode remained "C-AF" which it was originally. So apparently there is a difference between the button-controlled AF mode and the menu AF mode. Maybe somebody could explain the difference?

Comment: Do you have IS turned on or off on the lens? Do you have IS turned on or off on the camera?

Comment: IS is off on the lens. I think IS is on in the camera. What does IS have to do with autofocus?

Comment: Software conflicts can often have all kinds of different consequences. If the data bus is locked in an infinite loop because IS is tuned on for both the camera and lens, it might not allow the AF system the bandwidth it need to function.

Comment: You just totally changed the question from "Should this lens work with this camera" to "what is the difference between setting AF mode in the camera's menu and using the "AF" button.

Comment: @MichaelClark I am mainly interested in understanding the differences between the two modes, so I can understand why one is working with the Nocticron and the other is not. Ultimately, the question is the same: how can get the Nocticron AF to work properly on the EM1.

Comment: What does the manual say?

Comment: What happens when you set the menu to S-AF?

Comment: @TylerDurden That may have been what you wanted to know, but it is not what you asked as the question was originally worded.